# Problems installing the heroku eclipse plugin

Tags: heroku

I get this error

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: Heroku Eclipse Plugin 1.0.0 (com.heroku.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.0.0) Missing requirement: Heroku Eclipse Plugin 1.0.0 (com.heroku.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.0.0) requires 'org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.100' but it could not be found
```

I have eclipse Juno.

Let me know if I can support you with any other info to help resolve this issue.

I have Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Comment: The Eclipse plugin is deprecated. Please follow this guide instead: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error message.  Disabling my McAfee and then restarting fixed the problem for me.  I'm thinking it was a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. Please check your eclipse version. Heroku says it needs,
**Eclipse v 3.7 or higher (Java or Java EE edition)**
The following version works for me, **Indigo (v 3.7)**

Comment: It's not a good solution though, but you can use your Juno (4.2) for development and Indigo (3.7) with Heroku plugin to deploy your code.

Answer (score 0):

This (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.100) is referring to a plugin that is missing - the Maven Integration for Eclipse. Search the Eclipse Marketplace for that plugin. Once it's installed, try installing the Heroku plugin again. This worked for me on Indigo. It's weird that this isn't listed as a requirement.